Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Replace-by-Fee‽
Replace-by-Fee (RBF) is a flag that marks transactions as replaceable until they are confirmed.
Currently, we have eight questions about Replace-by-Fee, let's ask and learn! 
Please use replace-by-fee to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about behavior, effect, implementation, benefits, criticism, or whatever else you want to know about it.
This weekly topic challenge runs until 2016-11-10. Happy posting!

So far, one question has been asked about Replace-by-Fee:

What restrictions are there to the application of opt-in RBF?

