Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about replace-by-fee‽ [2022 edition, Finished]
Replace-by-fee has been a hot topic in the past few months. Our site already has 82 questions, but we probably have not everything covered yet.
Please use replace-by-fee to tag your questions, and consider asking about opt-in RBF, mempoolfullrbf, the criteria to evaluate replacement transactions, and any details on the mechanisms per which transactions in the mempool get replaced.
Please also check out previous work, add more answers where they are missing, improve content where it should be improved, and vote on what's there!
This weekly topic challenge runs from 2022-12-08 – 2022-12-14. Happy posting!

I realized that this was actually a topic in 2016 when we last did weekly topics as well: https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/5406

There were two questions asked about replace-by-fee during the challenge which each got one answer:

persistence of the RBF bit in post-fullrbf chain – Mercedes, answered by Michael Folkson
What are the arguments in the `mempoolfullrbf` debate? — Murch, answered by Michael Folkson

There were also three answers added to previously existing questions and more than twenty posts on replace-by-fee edited during the Topic Challenge!
Thanks for participating!
